# XPages Display Error Control not displaying - pop-up message appearing

Tags: xpages

I have a Display Error control on my XPage using this example:
[Error Management in XPages](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/error-management-in-xpages.htm#Display+Error+control)

Here is the code:

```xml
<xp:td>
                            <xp:inputText value="#{document1.ac_Email}" id="ac_Email1"
                                style="width:250px">
                                <xp:this.validators>
                                    <xp:validateRequired message="Email is a required field.">
                                    </xp:validateRequired>
                                    <xp:validateExpression
                                        message="Email needs to be in this format: john@acme.com">
                                        <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:value.match(/^([0-9a-zA-Z]+([_.-]?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9,a-z,A-Z,.,-]*(.){1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/)}]]></xp:this.expression>
                                    </xp:validateExpression>
                                </xp:this.validators>
                            </xp:inputText>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:message id="message1" for="ac_Email1"></xp:message>
                        </xp:td>
```

If the email is not formatted correctly -- using the validateExpression -- the display error message appears correctly.  If the field is empty, a pop-up message (in Firefox) appears.  Based on the example and what I coded, the display error control message should appear, not the pop-up message.

I am confused since I have two other fields on the form that, when empty, work correctly -- the required field message appears in the display error control to the right of the field.  Is it because there are 2 validators on this field?

Thanks!

Comment: Just checking, but are the application properties are set to prevent client-side validation? It sounds like they are, but always good to check.

Comment: In the Application Properties > XPages, the Client Validation is set to Server Default.  I set to Off and it works correctly now.  I guess my next question is if the email field is filled in correctly and the next field is not populated, the display error message appears correctly -- why?  Why would one field display as a pop-up but the others do not?  Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: So does it work now that you have changed client validation?

Comment: @Dan: You can explicitly disable the client side validation for each field with the *disableClientSideValidation* property.

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten -- Yes, setting Client Validation to Off corrected my issue.

Comment: @Sven - thanks for that information.  I am going to try that out on each of the fields.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Sven, move your comment to the answer, so you can get proper recognition for solving the issue. Btw. Happy birthday

Comment: Validate Expression does not work client-side. That's why you don't get pop-up box for e-mail format.

Comment: Can we start putting these suggestions in answers instead of comments so that these questions stop showing up as unanswered, please?

Comment: I just benefited from Sven's comment and would like to give him credit.  I am going to echo Notes sensei and ask you to answer this Sven since your answer is most definitely correct.